# Are my MySQL connection details safe using this method?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page. Within this page there is a php script to connect to MySQL. I have MySQL settings saved separately in `connection.inc`. So, to connect to MySQL, I insert into the php script `include(connection.inc)`.

I am just wondering whether this is the safest option as I can type `www.example.com/connection.inc` into my browser and login details can be seen.

Even thought the php script cannot be seen when you right click and view source in a browser, I know you can get software that can find out the php script.

Comment: `I know you can get software that can find out the php script` oh?

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not safe. This is called *security by obscurity*.

You should place `connection.inc` outside of the web-accessible directory (`www-docs`) - PHP will still be able to read it, but users on the Internet won't be able to grab the file with a `GET` request.

Answer (score 1):

Not safe at all. Make sure `connection.inc` is not accessible at all. A few options (some of these can be combined), ordered from easiest/fastest to implement to somewhat more work to implement.

1. Rename it to `connection.php` and make sure the contents are wrapped
   in `<?php` tags.
2. If 1, also add a header redirect to your main page (e.g. `index.php`).
3. Place it outside a web accessible directory
4. Block access to it using `.htaccess`
5. Configure Apache (for this site) not to serve `.inc` files
6. Ensure MySQL user and password are limited (can only select, insert, delete or update) and that only connections from this machine are allowed to access it.

Comment: thanks for your help. so my script for connection.php is: <?php header('location: index.html') [new line] include(connection.inc). obvs on new line? how do I configure apcahe for this site? I am using my host providers server

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, if you header redirect, you need to make sure that the file they requested is connection.inc. Othewise if you include connection.inc in about.php, the site will redirect to index.php.

If it's a shared host, you probably can't edit apache, but should be able to do the same using .htaccess. search for FileMatch and Rewrite options to automatically redirect.

Comment: I was wrong, you don't need rewrite, you can include this in your root .htaccess file:

`<Files ~ "\.inc$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>`

Comment: I have found a .htacess generator on my webhosting options however i am not sure what I am doing. I have a 'Set Default Index Page' which i have put index.html. it then gives me an option on where to place the .htaccess on my ftp server. once generated it then gives me. it now says     1. Copy the generated code and paste it into an already existing .htaccess file.
    2. Save the file/file content in the chosen and above specified location.
If my connection.ini is in my root folder what do i need to do now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

At least name the file that contains your login credentials with a `.php` extension and the appropriate `<?php` and `?>` tags wrapping said info.  Ideally, you wouldn't keep those credentials in **any** web-accessible directory.  Just having a `.php` extension isn't 100% foolproof, as a web server misconfiguration could temporarily prevent PHP from parsing its scripts with the interpreter or could break .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

`conncetion.inc` is safe in the sense that it will never be executed - unless you configure your server to interpret `.inc` files as PHP

If it's in a web accessible folder visitors might browse to it and see the contents of the file, so don't put any passwords there.

Good places to store (MySQL) passwords is:

- in a PHP file (because you can't read the source code)
- outside of the web root
- in a file that is blocked by Apache (like `.ht#`). You can add custom deny-blocks.

Comment: so i confirm I should: include(connection.php) then within connection.php I put include(config.php)

Comment: Yes, that would hide your passwords.

Comment: but, i read you can get software that can read php scripts? http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/Snippets/view-php-source-4451.html

Comment: If you have a script that will read a file (like a PHP script) and post the contents in plain-text, then you have a serious security issue. But this requires you to have that script on your server. A hacker could put it there but if a hacker can put an executable file on your server you have bigger problems. **Under normal circumstance it's not possible to view the source code of a PHP file.**